# Calculating dates excluding weekends in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to calculate the number of days between a range excluding weekends. The code that I've come up with right now excludes only Saturdays but not Sundays. For instance, my code returns 1 instead of 0 when the start and end dates are 24-SEP-2022(Saturday) and 25-SEP-2022(Sunday). Similarly, 25-SEP-2022(Sunday) and 26-SEP-2022(Monday) returns 2 when they should have returned 1.

Here is my code:

```
String method(String start, String end) {
  int a = 1;
  DateTime startDate = DateTime.parse(start);
  DateTime endDate = DateTime.parse(end);

  while (startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
    startDate = startDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    if (startDate.weekday != DateTime.saturday &&
        startDate.weekday != DateTime.sunday) {
      a++;
    }
  }
  print('COUNT: $start :: $end $a');
  return a.toString();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You did not pay attention to `a`! You have initiated `a = 1`, but in this case it has to be `0`. because of that it always returns one more day.

Comment: The other issue I'm facing now is that the count attained for weekdays is 1 day less than what it should be. For instance, the count for 10-10-2022 and 14-10-2022 returns 4 days instead of 5. 10th was a Monday while the 14 was Friday.